# How to implement tf.gather with some other tf ops

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to replace tf.gather with some simple and common tf ops like concat,stack,reshape,slice etc to achieve the same result, because tf.gather is not supported in some deployment framework currently(e.g. [the operators that ncnn supports](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/wiki/operators#packing)).

Test code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 
params = np.random.rand(5, 2)
params = tf.constant(params)
print("==>> params: ", params)
indices = np.random.randint(low=0,high=5, size=(3,3))
indices = tf.constant(indices)
print("==>> indices: ", indices)
result = tf.gather(params, indices)  # to reimplement it
print("==>> result: ", result)
print("==>> result.shape: ", result.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, they can create two different images with eye-seeing information or as in the video game we play for safe available bandwidths.
Tf.Gather can implement in many useful ways that include selective information.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Working
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
IMAGE_1 = plt.imread("C:\\Users\\Jirayu Kaewprateep\\Pictures\\Cats\\206480490_10158968022281077_7829901115614154740_n_10158968022276077.jpg")
IMAGE_1 = tf.image.resize(IMAGE_1, [log_scales_height, log_scales_width]).numpy()
IMAGE_1 = tf.constant( IMAGE_1, dtype=tf.int32 ).numpy()

params = plt.imread("C:\\Users\\Jirayu Kaewprateep\\Pictures\\Cats\\206480490_10158968022281077_7829901115614154740_n_10158968022276077.jpg")
params = tf.reshape( params, ( params.shape[0] * params.shape[1], 3 ))

limit = tf.math.divide( params.shape[0] * params.shape[1], delta, name='Devide' ).numpy()
limit = 414720
limit = 691200
indices = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
result = tf.gather(params, indices)                 
result = tf.reshape( result, (240, 288, 3) )        

plt.figure(figsize=(1,2))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(IMAGE_1)
plt.xlabel(" rescaling ")

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.xlabel(" logarithms pictires ")

plt.show()
input('...')
```

**[ Output ]:**
*See the attache picture.*

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBEeY.png)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't describe my question clearly, the sample code seems that it is not what I expect, I don't konw what is the value of delta, and why you still use tf.gather in the sample code. My goal is to replace tf.gather with some other tf ops to achieve the same result.

Comment: I just example of one method over tf.gather it had its own benefit over selective action but matrixes example also.

Comment: 2. I example of two similar tasks doing with tf.gather and indices matrixes.